# Put a label beside a text entry in python gtk

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

So I'm trying to build a pretty basic GUI using python GTK, but I'm getting frustrated very quickly.  How do I put my label beside my text entry?  How can I make the entry smaller? The button smaller?  I'm going to have to add more entries and take them all in at once to process the information, and I don't necessarily need them to fill the window...  Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


class text_box:
    #Callback function, data arguments are ignored
    def hello(self, widget, entry):
        entry_text = self.entry.get_text()
        print("Entry contents: ".format(entry_text))


    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        #Return of FALSE deletes event, True keeps it
        print("Delete even occurred")
        return False

    def submit(self, button):
        try:
            input = self.entry.get_text()
            print(float(input))
            return input
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a number...")
            self.md = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, "This is not a number")
            self.md.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
            self.md.run()
            self.md.destroy()


    def enter(self, button):
        try:
            input = self.entry.get_text()
            input = float(input)
            print(input)
            return input
        except ValueError:
            self.md = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, "This is not a number")
            self.md.run()
            self.md.destroy()
            print("This is not a number...")



    #Another Callback
    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        self.fix = gtk.Fixed()

        #create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(500, 500)
        self.window.set_title("Powder Application")
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        vbox = gtk.VBox(False,0)
        self.window.add(vbox)
        vbox.show()

        #When window is given delete_event, close
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        #Connect the "destroy" event to a signal handler
        #Occurs with gtk_widget_destroy() or False in delete_event
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        #Sets border width of window
        self.window.set_border_width(10)

        #Creates button
        self.button = gtk.Button("Submit")
        #self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)

        #Submit data in window on click
        self.button.connect_object("clicked", self.submit, self.window)


        #Make entry box
        self.entry = gtk.Entry()
        self.label = gtk.Label("Powder Density")
        vbox.pack_start(self.label, False, False, 0)
        self.label.show()
        self.entry.set_max_length(20)
        self.entry.select_region(0, len(self.entry.get_text()))
        #self.entry.connect("activate", self.hello, self.entry)
        self.entry.connect_object("activate", self.enter, self.window)
        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, False, False, 0)
        self.entry.show()

        #This packs the button and entry into the window
        #self.window.add(self.button)
        #self.window.add(self.entry)

        #hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        #vbox.add(hbox)
        #hbox.show()

        #The final step is to display this newly created widget.
        vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, False, 00)
        self.button.show()

        #And the window
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        #All PyGTK apps must have a gtk.main().  Control ends here
        #and waits for an event to occur 
        gtk.main()
        return 0


#If the program is run, create a gui instance and show it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello = text_box()
    hello.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [Table](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTable.html) and add the table to the window using:

```
table=Gtk.Table(1,4,True)
table.attach(label,0,1,0,1)
table.attach(entry,1,3,0,1)
table.attach(button,3,4,0,1)
window.add(table)
window.show_all()
```

This displays the label beside the text box, with the button beside it

Comment: "This displays the label beside the text bo[x]"  So it does... But it centers it vertically and horizontally (not wanted) and my button is no where to be found...  And what do the numbers correspond to?  I can get my button in, but it takes up an entire side of the window, again, not wanted.

Comment: This displays the label beside the text box, with the button beside it and the button is as tall as the entire window.  What do the numbers correspond to?

Comment: All the three objects will be of the same size, as of the window.. If you want to reduce it, increase the number of rows and columns.. As of to the numbers, refer the link i posted

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties to `False`, and the `halign` and `valign` properties to something other than `Gtk.Align.FILL`, so that the widgets don't take up the maximum space.